# How to get total value into a double or a vector

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I want to get all the "Amount" value total of specific account number into a double or into a vector. Because of my database having many transactions for same account number i can't figure out how to get total value of all the records.My code giving me the last transaction amount value only not the sum of all. Appreciate any help

```
 ResultSet rs5 = (ResultSet) st1.executeQuery("SELECT Amount FROM  Incoming_Transactions WHERE  AccountNumber LIKE '" + accountnum+  "%'");
        while (rs5.next()) {
            Vector <Double> em = new Vector();
            em.add(rs5.getDouble("Amount"));

            Double [] myArray = em.toArray(new Double[0]);
            check2 = myArray[0];


        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every iteration of your while loop, you are resetting your `Vector<Double> em`.  That means only the most recent element actually ends up in your loop.  Fix this by moving the declaration of your `Vector` outside the loop like so

```
Vector <Double> em = new Vector();
ResultSet rs5 = (ResultSet) st1.executeQuery("SELECT Amount FROM  Incoming_Transactions WHERE  AccountNumber LIKE '" + accountnum+  "%'");
    while (rs5.next()) {       
         em.add(rs5.getDouble("Amount"));
    }
Double [] myArray = new Double[em.size()]; 
myArray = em.ToArray(myArray);
//Now do stuff with all the entries
```

If you only are interested in the sum, you can move the sum into the query itself like Eran suggests, or declare a sum variable outside the loop and update it every loop like this:

```
Double runningSum = 0.0;
ResultSet rs5 = (ResultSet) st1.executeQuery("SELECT Amount FROM  Incoming_Transactions WHERE  AccountNumber LIKE '" + accountnum+  "%'");
    while (rs5.next()) {
        runningSum += rs5.getDouble("Amount");
    }
```

Comment: Thanx alot. Works like a magic. Ive moved the sum into the query itself. Highly appreciate.

Comment: @Rufphel you can only mark one answer as accepted, but you can **upvote** any and all helpful answers.  Accept the most helpful answer (since you mentioned you moved the sum into the query probably Eran's answer).

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the sum of all the amounts, and don't care about individual amounts, you can get it directly from executing the SQL query :

```
SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM  Incoming_Transactions WHERE  AccountNumber LIKE '" + accountnum+  "%'"
```

If you to fetch the individual amounts for the given account and calculate the sum yourself, you can iterate over the `myArray` array or `em` Vector and add all the amounts. If you choose this approach, move the initialization of `em` outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Below query will return account number and respective sum of amount

```
Select accountnumber,sum(amount) from Incoming_Transactions WHERE  AccountNumber LIKE '" + accountnum+  "%' group by accountnumber
```

Also, if you don't want to modify query you can use map wherein accountnumer is key and value will be amount. If you already have account number in map add amount into current amount value otherwise add new account into map